How to fix misaligned objects that look fine in viewport but not in render?
I'm experimenting with a new style that involves linking objects to a surface using the magnetic icon (snap) --> centre, faces, and align rotation to target. It looks fine in the viewport, but when I render it, elements like the eyebrows, blush, and even the eyes appear off.
I've definitely come across such an issue before where things look fine in the viewport but not in render but I dont recall how to fix it. Should I be applying my modifiers?

How can I fix this?

Edit 1:

Hello could you please share your file https://blend-exchange.com? Remove all the useless objects and do a File > Cleanup.

The levels for preview and render are not the same in your Subdivision Surface modifiers, align the render value with the preview:


I cant believe I missed it. Thank you for your help as always!
